# Isn't it possible to query Firebase Database children(not keys) in combination of queryStartinAtValue and queryEndingAtValue?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to query my data such that I get the objects whose timeStamps are in the range of my desired timeStamps.

My JSON data is:

```
"-KHbFGKIyefgWKEmlkY1" : {
      "createdAt" : 1463094941,
      "customer" : "user1",
      "professional" : "professional1",
      "service" : "service2",
      "startsAt" : 1470070000,
      "status" : "WaitingForApproval"
    }
```

My code to make the query:

```
let minimumDesiredTimeStamp = 1470000000
let maximumDesiredTimeStamp = 1480000000

ref.queryOrderedByChild("startsAt")
   .queryStartingAtValue(minimumDesiredTimeStamp)
   .queryEndingAtValue(maximumDesiredTimeStamp)
   .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshotOfChildrenWhichStartsAtTimeStampRange) in 

})
```

The problem is that query never jumps in the closure. 
If it's not possible with current Firebase , can you suggest a way on how to achieve this?

**NOTE**: For now, I've solved the problem by querying with only combining *queryOrderedByChild*  and *queryStartingAtValue* and then filtering the objects whose start time exceeds my range, with the help of Swift arrays' filter method.

**NOTE2**: When I tried the code again with hard coded values, I realised that the query really works. So it seems I've misidentified the problem and something else causing the query not jumping in the closure. 
So *remember*: querying child values in combination of *queryOrderedByChild*.*queryStartingAtValue*.*queryEndingAtValue* works!

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit hard to parse that query without seeing the corresponding JSON (as text, no screenshots please).

Comment: Here is my json format: 


"-KHbFGKIyefgWKEmlkY1" : {"createdAt" : 1463094941,  
"customer" : "user1",  
     "professional" : "professional1",  
     "service" : "service2",  
     "startsAt" : 1470070000,  
     "status" : "WaitingForApproval"  
    }

(Sorry for the bad formatting, I couldn't achieve any better.)

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38682422/edit) to add the JSON. Keep in mind: the easier you make it to help, the more likely it is that we'll be able to answer. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience Frank. I've edited the question.

Comment: As far as I can tell the filter should work. But there is a lot of information still missing here, such as the values of `minimumDesiredTimeStamp` and `maximumDesiredTimeStamp` and the output that you get (and what you expected instead). Without seeing a so-called [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is really tough to help.

Comment: I've edited the question again. Sorry, I always write in a hurry and try to spend minimum amount of time to explain the problem in an understandable way. But it seems that it's not working. :) 

I have just tried the code again and you are right the filter really works. So it seems I'd misidentified the problem. Thank you for your kind comments Frank!

Comment: Good to hear it now works Murat.